# Different error handler for each app in Django project

Tags: django, error-handling

I am developing a Django 1.3 project that contains multiple apps. The project structure is somewhat like this:

```
- MyProject
  - manage.py
  - MyProject
    - settings.py
    - url.py
    - wsgi.py
  - core
    - models.py
  - web
    - urls.py
    - views.py
  - api
    - urls.py
    - views.py
```

I would now like to define different handler404 and handler500 for the `api` app, since it is supposed to return JSON while `web` returns HTML and can use the default handlers.

Is there a way to override this setting so it is valid for just one app? I really like to avoid running multiple server instances just because of that.

Thanks Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `httphandler404` is global for a site. In your case, you will have to write a wrapper view which depending upon url (or some other attribute in `request`) either returns JSON for `api` app and HTML for `web` app. You can also define separate error handling views in `api` and `web` can call them from wrapper view.

Reference : [Customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view)

Answer (score 1):

You can define global 404 and 500 handlers which dispatch to specific error handlers depending on the request content-type, accept-encoding, and/or path. Those specific handler functions can of course live in your app modules.